# PDE - Don't understand teacher's solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

I'm reading a solution to a problem in PDE class that the teacher gave, and I don't fully understand his solution.

The problem is $\frac{dx}{1+\sqrt{z-x-y}}=dy=\frac{dz}{2}$ and what we want is to find $2$ functions $F_1(x,y,z)=C_1$ and $F_2(x,y,z)=C_2$.

Here is what the teacher did:

We know $dy=\frac{dz}{2}$, just integrate left side with respect to $y$, right side with respect to $z$ to get $F_1(x,y,z)=y-\frac{1}{2}z=C_1$. No problems there.

My problem is with $F_2$. He writes:

$\frac{dx}{1+\sqrt{z-x-y}}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dz}{2}$ implies $\frac{dz-dy-dx}{2-1-(1+\sqrt{z-x-y})}=dy$ if and only if $\frac{d(z-x-y)}{2-1-(1+\sqrt{z-x-y})}=dy$ if and only if $\frac{d(z-x-y)}{-\sqrt{z-x-y}}=y+C_2$ if and only if $-2\sqrt{z-x-y}=y+C_2$ and now we have $F_2(x,y,z)=-2\sqrt{z-x-y}-y=C_2$.

I don't fully understand what he did.

Firstly, why can we say that $dz-dy-dz=d(z-y-x)$? what if $z$ is a function of $x,y$? I don't think it would be true then. Maybe true if $x,y,z$ are independent.

But mainly, why does $\frac{dx}{1+\sqrt{z-x-y}}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dz}{2}$ implies $\frac{dz-dy-dx}{2-1-(1+\sqrt{z-x-y})}=dy$?

The rest I understood.

Comment: Try it out with real fraction and see why it makes sense. $\frac{3}{2}$ for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d$ is a [linear differential operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator#Properties_of_differential_operators) so that $d(z-y-x)=dz-dy-dx\,$ independently of the dependencies.

Concerning the last part rewrite $\;\displaystyle\frac{dx}{1+\sqrt{z-x-y}}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dz}{2}\;$ in function of $dy$ to get $dz=2\,dy,\;dy=dy\;$ and $\;dx=(1+\sqrt{z-x-y})\;dy$.

Express then $\;dz-dy-dx\,$ in function of $\,dy$.

Comment: Glad it clarified @Oria Gruber (many people get confused by the $\frac {dx}{\cdots}=\frac {dy}{\cdots}=\cdots$ things btw). Fine continuation,